# How to get method argument value in joinpoint.getArgs()?

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

```
    String type = "";
if("searchClientContactDetails".equalsIgnoreCase(methodName) || "getClientAndVendorOrgDeatilsById".equalsIgnoreCase(methodName) 
                || "saveVenodrContact".equalsIgnoreCase(methodName) || "getSpocAndOwnerDetailsById".equalsIgnoreCase(methodName)
                || "terminateSpoc".equalsIgnoreCase(methodName)){
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
            Object arg=args[0];
            Class c=arg.getClass();
            type=(String)c.getMethod("getResponderType").invoke(arg);
}
```

From the above code if my getResponderType value is in the args[0] then i am getting the required value , what if my value is present in args[1] or args[2] (using the same for multiple methods). In my code i will get the "getResponderType" value in first argument for few methods and in another methods i will be getting it in  second or third argument.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you provide the methods declarations. 
Because for

```
 void searchClientContactDetails(String a, Integer b);      
 void searchClientContactDetails(Long a, String b);
```

your

```
Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
Object arg=args[0];
```

will be return different values.

Maybe it is your problem )

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `args` looking for the method `getResponderType`. Once you find what you are looking for, you can break.

```
String type = "";
Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
for (Object arg : args) {
    Class clazz = arg.getClass();
    try {
        Method mthd = arg.getClass().getMethod("getResponderType");
        if (mthd != null) {
            type = (String) clazz.getMethod(
                            "getResponderType").invoke(arg);
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```