# how to get a String value called token from method in order to use spring AOP to write a shorter code

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, aop

for example in my project i have class called AdminController that have lots of methods with code that repeat itself in all of the methods and have a class variable, one of the methods + class variable is this:

```
   private Map<String, OurSession> clientSessions;

    public AdminController(Map<String, OurSession> clientSessions) {
        this.clientSessions = clientSessions;
    }

    @PostMapping("addCompany/{token}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addCompany(@PathVariable String token, @RequestBody Company company){
        OurSession session = clientSessions.get(token);
        if(session != null){
            AdminFacade admin = (AdminFacade) session.getFacade();
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - session.getLastAccessed() > 1000 * 60 * 30)
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("UNAUTHORIZED login");
            session.setLastAccessed(System.currentTimeMillis());
            try {
                admin.addCompany(company);
                return ResponseEntity.ok(company);
            } catch (CompanyAlreadyExistsException e) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage());
            }
        }else
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("UNAUTHORIZED login");
    }
```

now inside this method all of this code is repeat itself in all of this class methods:

```
 OurSession session = clientSessions.get(token);
        if(session != null){
            AdminFacade admin = (AdminFacade) session.getFacade();
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - session.getLastAccessed() > 1000 * 60 * 30)
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("UNAUTHORIZED login");
            session.setLastAccessed(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

this code can be inserted in a AOP method in another class to help me write less code:

```
    @Before("execution(* com.example.couponproject.controller.AdminController*(..) )")
    public void runBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        code here that repeat itself

    }
```

but my problem is that you notice that all of the method get a String value called token and i dont know how to get the AOP method use that, how do i sent this token value each time the AOP method runs?

in other word i need the AOP method use this token value from each controller method that called the AOP method

thanks for helpers!

Comment: joinPoint.getArgs(), S. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028651/how-to-get-method-argument-value-in-joinpoint-getargs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the methods of the class `AdminController` have `String token` as the first argument , `args()` Pointcut designator can be used for this purpose.

Example code :

```
@Before("execution(* com.example.couponproject.controller.AdminController*(..) ) && args(token,..)")
public void runBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint,String token) {
    code here that repeat itself

}
```

Read through the section [Passing Parameters to Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing) for more information on the same

Thanks to @kriegaex for pointing this out ( quoting his comment ) :

> On a side note: Maybe the OP's class is named AdminController and he
> want to match all methods in that class. Then he should use
> .AdminController.*, because .AdminController* would match a (strangely
> named) method name starting with AdminController in an (also strangely
> named) class controller. I assume that is not the case here, so
> probably .AdminController.* it is

Comment: Additionally, you could narrow down to `String` arguments which also have a `@PathVariable` annotation if that is helpful. Something like `execution(* com.example.couponproject.controller.AdminController*(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable (*), ..))`, if I am not mistaken (I did not test the syntax, but as far as I remember it should be like that). BTW, instead of `(*)` you could also write the more explicit `(java.lang.String)`, but it would be redundant because the parameter is implicitly typed via the advice method argument binding already.

Comment: On a side note: Maybe the OP's class is named `AdminController` and he wants to match all methods in that class. Then he should use `.AdminController.*`, because `.AdminController*` would match a (strangely named) method name starting with `AdminController` in an (also strangely named) class `controller`. I assume that is not the case here, so probably `.AdminController.*` it is.